# Use filename on dataframe and match it with another list and store the list element

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I wanted to take the list element based on the dataframe 'filename'.
I have a method but its too many loops and time consuming, is there a good and best method?

```
import pandas as pd

a = pd.DataFrame({'Filename':['fileA', 'FileB'],
                  'Random':['random', 'only']})
b = ['this-is-another-fileA', 'this-is-another-fileB', 'this-is-another-fileC', 'this-is-another-fileD'] # this might have more than thousands of data

list_a = a['Filename'].tolist()
finding = []
for l in list_a:
    for file in b:
        if l in file:
            finding.append(file)
```

expected output:

```
['this-is-another-fileA']
```

Comment: Is the file name in `b` always in the last position and separated with a dash?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need two loops to match one list against another list, no matter what. Perhaps you can make the loops more efficient, **assuming that the file names are always after the last dash**, by converting to sets:

```
setA = set(a['Filename']) # A set of file names

# A dictionary of full b's and their file names
splits = {x.rsplit("-", 1)[-1] : x for x in b} 

# The b's that are both in A and b:
[splits[x] for x in setA & splits.keys()] 
#['this-is-another-fileA']
```

Your sample is too small to tell if this approach is better than the original code, but it is *supposed* to be faster because sets have a much better lookup time than lists.

Answer (score 1):

```
a = pd.DataFrame({'Filename':['fileA', 'FileB']})
b = ['this-is-another-fileA', 'this-is-another-fileB', 'this-is-another-fileC', 'this-is-another-fileD']
b = [x.rsplit("-", 1)[-1] for x in b]
x= a[a['Filename'].isin(b)]
```

Output :

```
  Filename
0    fileA
>>>
```

Thanks to DYZ for the idea of using rsplit to remove dashes.

Comment: yes, i think about that too but if possible i wanted to run away from looping. is it possible.>

Comment: a[a['Filename'].isin(b)] is that what are you looking for? This will give you the Filenames that are in b list on the current column or you can do this with a new Series object with only files included on b,  x = a['Filename'].isin(b)

Comment: but somehow,there is nothing in the datafrme.

Comment: yea, my bad, you should apply a regex before appplying that removing all but fileA from b list as DYZ proposed.

Comment: I made some changes to my answer and undeleted it.